# Confidence Intervals for Non-normal data?

Tags: confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution

I have a dataset where the response is the number of successes and I have two factor variables A, B (A has 6 levels and B has 4 levels) and a quantitative variable H (H is hours so it is non-negative).  The number of trials is fixed for different levels of A -- A1 always has 20 trials, A2 always 12, etc).  The dataset looks like the following:

```
A   B   H   Success Trials
A1  B2  0.5    5      20
A2  B3  0.75   7      12
A4  B1  3      0      15
A6  B4  2      3      4
... ... ...   ...     ...
```

I'm mainly interested in predicting the expected number of successes.  I fit a binomial regression in R with interactions to this data in order to get the probability of success:
`(Success, Trials - Success) ~ A + B + H + A:H + B:H`

From this GLM I can get confidence intervals for the success probability given A, B, H.  Since the number of trials is fixed for different levels of A, I can also get a confidence interval on the expected number of successes.  However, the specifications for this project also call for confidence intervals for the number of successes given A alone (ignoring B and H) and confidence intervals for number of successes given B alone (ignoring A and H).

Basically they want a confidence intervals on the number of successes for the different levels of A, ignoring other variables and then confidence intervals on number of successes for different levels of B, ignoring other variables.

I want to know the best way to get these confidence intervals.  One approach I have tried so far is to take the vcov from my GLM and I have basically averaged out the coefficients for the levels of factor variables I'm "ignoring" and for H I'm just using the overall average number of hours.

Slightly more technically to get the SE for my confidence intervals, I'm making a C vector and taking `sqrt(C %*% vcov(glm_model) %*% t(C))`.  Suppose my vcov matrix has rows that correspond to the following factor levels:

```
(intercept)
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
A6
B1
B2
B3
B4
H
```

The C-vector associated with the first row of my data frame above would be: `(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.5)`

The approach I have tried so far if I wanted a confidence interval for A1, ignoring all levels of B and H is to use the following C-vector: `(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, Overall Average H)`.  This will use an average value of H and average out the effect of variable B.

Is there a better way to get confidence intervals than what I've done above (including non-GLM ways)?  I've looked at things like Clopper-Pearson and I'm not sure if it's applicable here.

Edit: I guess I forgot to mention that the number of successes is not normal (not even close) so the normal mean +/- 1.96 * SE won't work.  The number of successes in my actual dataset has a lot of zeroes.

Comment: I'm wondering, whether, before performing GLM analysis, it would make sense to _impute_ the data, as you mentioned that your data set has a lot of _missing values_ (I have assumed that "zeroes" implied missing data - sorry, if my assumption was wrong).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, there are no missing data issues with this dataset.  There are a lot of rows where the number of successes is 0 -- making a simple normal distribution type confidence interval even less useful.

Comment: No problem, it is clear now. Thank you for clarification.